# Scene from Taxi Teheran staged?

Tags: taxi-2015

Are the scenes from Taxi Teheran staged by actors? It looks too much of a coincidence that what happend in the movie to be real.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Taxi (2015 film)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxi_(2015_film)) at Wikipedia:

> .. The passengers are played by non-professional **actors,** whose identities remain anonymous.